# Which statistical distribution model should I use to determine, with 95% confidence, the likelihood that the mean of a sample population is 0.5?

Tags: statistics

To give more detail, I'm trying to rank comments on a webpage where users can either like or dislike a comment. I specifically want to rank highest, the comments which divided users the most. This means the like/dislike ratio should be as close as possible to 0.5. I know that my like/dislike functionality is a form of a Bernoulli parameter. I also want comment A (50 likes/51 dislikes) to rank higher than comment B (1 like/1 dislike), which means I need to incorporate a Wilson confidence interval. I'm a bit rusty on my statistics, though, so I can't remember the formula that puts this all together.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full disclosure: I'm a biological statistician without much experience in such matters.  If there are commonly-used techniques or conventions, I probably haven't heard of them.

That being said, it seems to me that conventional frequentist statistics don't really answer this question well.  Hypothesis testing typically looks for the strength of evidence that a parameter is NOT equal to some value, with more and more data typically providing more evidencial weight to the inequality.  A confidence interval approach like you're describing is better (you could give weights based on the width of the interval) - but it's not terrifically obvious what to do when 0.5 is not in the interval.  Note: there are a few ways of constructing confidence intervals for a binomial p parameter, and there isn't really a "wrong" way.

Here's a slightly ad-hoc solution that might actually work well (and has some Bayesian underpinnings): use a Beta distribution instead.  The Beta is defined by two parameters (a & b), with probability density defined as

```
f(y)=((a+b-1)!/((a-1)!(b-1)!)(y^(a-1))((1-y)^(b-1))
```

It's defined on the interval (0,1), and typically looks like a bump of probability mass at a/(a+b).  You can think of the *a* and *b* as two dueling parameters trying to pull the bump in either direction.  The interesting thing is the bump gets taller & skinnier as *a* and *b* get larger, even if the ratio is the same.

If you have R, try plotting

```
curve(dbeta(x,10,10))
curve(dbeta(x,5,5), add=T, col="red")
curve(dbeta(x,2,2), add=T, col="blue")
```

So, use your number of "yes" votes for *a* and number of "no" votes for *b*, and then you can think of the resulting Beta distribution describing the probability distribution of the underlying *p* parameter.  Mathematically, this is equivalent to a Bayesian Beta-binomial model, with a Beta(0,0) prior.

For weighting, you could integrate the probability mass defined by a region between 0.45 and 0.55 (or narrower or wider) ... or easier still, you could even use the height of the curve at y=0.5!

Again, in R, using the curve-height idea...

```
### some trial weights
dbeta(0.5, 1, 1)  # one yes, one no
# 1

dbeta(0.5, 2, 2)  # 2 yes, 2 no
# 1.5

dbeta(0.5, 4, 6)  # 4 yes, 6 no
# 1.96875

dbeta(0.5, 3, 7)  # 3 yes, 7 no
# 0.984375

dbeta(0.5, 49, 51)  # 49 yes, 51 no
# 7.799745
```

It's up to you, but seems fairly workable to me.

Comment: To see if this model would work for me, I made a 3D graph of all the 0.5 values from (1, 1) to (100, 100). [Here it is](https://plot.ly/~barinska/5/), if you're curious.